# Prevent mustache.js templates from loading images using template syntax

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, mustache

Simple question: I have a few mustache templates in the front end of the code, many with image tags with a source set to a variable set by mustache js. that is..

```
<img src="{{img_src}}" />
```

This is causing the server to load images with a url of root/{{img_src}}, which is unideal. How can I prevent them from being preloaded?

Comment: This sounds like [an XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). I think the better question here is: why is the browser receiving (and interpreting as HTML) raw templates?

Answer (score 7):

Sounds like you're storing your templates in `<div>`s (or similar HTML wrappers) like this:

```
<div id="t" style="display: none">
    <img src="{{img_src}}" />
<div>
```

If you do things like that, you're telling the browser that your template is HTML when it isn't; if you tell the browser to interpret something as HTML you should expect it to do so. The solution is to use a `<script>` container:

```
<script id="t" type="text/x-mustache">
    <img src="{{img_src}}" />
</script>
```

[`<script>`s](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/script.html) contain non-replaceable character data rather than HTML so the browser won't see the `<img>` inside the `<script>` as an HTML `img` element and it won't try to resolve the `src` attribute.